# Annotation not found on object with Runtime retention

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Ok, I'm a little bit confused here. I'm trying to select a "DAO" class by using an annotation on the model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dispatcher")
// use the Kamailio Base DAO for code that supports this annotation
@DAOSelector(dao = DAOBaseKamailio.class) 
public class DispatcherSet extends Model {
    [...]
}
```

Here is the annotation defenition:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface DAOSelector {
       Class<?> dao();
}
```

I use the following code to return the proper "DAO" class:

```
public static DAOInterface getCorrectDAO(final Object object) throws Exception {
  final DAOSelector annotation = 
    object.getClass().getAnnotation(DAOSelector.class);

  if(annotation != null) {
    System.out.println("Annotation present: " + 
      annotation.dao().getName() + " for class " + object.getClass().getName());

    final Object dao = annotation.dao().newInstance();
    if(!(dao instanceof DAOInterface)) {
      throw new Exception("Invalid Base DAO in annotation for entity " + 
        object.getClass().getName());
    }
    return (DAOInterface) dao;
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("Annotation not present for class " + 
      object.getClass().getName());
    return new DAOBase();
  }
}
```

However, when I feed a `DispatcherSet` object annotation is always null:

> 10:33:38,498 [INFO] [STDOUT] Annotation not present for class model.DispatcherSet

Am I missing something here?

edit:

OK, found something interesting, I'm running this code inside a JBoss container and when I print out all the annotations:

```
{{{
$Proxy76
$Proxy708
$Proxy77
}}}
```

One of these should be a proxied instance of the `DAOSelector` annotation I'm guessing, so that's probably why `getAnnotation(DAOSelector.class)` won't work, checking it out.

edit2:

Nope, they are not an instance of `DAOSelector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed the problem. it was a classpath issue. I have an ear containing a jar and war. The model was in the jar and the annotation was present in both.